# compact set always contains its supremum and infimum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, compactness, supremum-and-infimum

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb R$. Prove that $\sup K$ and $\inf K$ exist and are in $K$.

My approach: As $K$ is compact, it is bounded. So $\sup K$ and $\inf K$ exists. The reason is that:

Since $K$ is compact, there exist $k_1, \cdots , k_n \in \mathbb R$ such that

$$K \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^n  (-k_j,k_j)$$

If $N = \max\{k_1,\cdots, k_n\}$, then $K$ is a subset of $(-N,N)$. Hence $K$ is bounded. 
since $K$ is bounded by $-N$ and $N$, $\sup K$ and $\inf K$ exists.

Is this good enough? Is boundedness guaranteed the existence of supremum and infimum?

Comment: It's not enough for a proof, because the sup, inf may not belong to $K$.Note that a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ (and therefore $\mathbb R^1$ is closed, so that it contains its limit points, and sup, inf are limit points.

Comment: Hi, what is the definition of a compact set?

Comment: Compact $\Rightarrow$ closed and bounded. Which is what you need.

Comment: Hi john , thank you for editing ,what did u used to write the mathmatical formula things?

Comment: @sayuri: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Nate El. arigatoo

Comment: Is closed condition necessary for inf and sup?

Comment: @user99680 $\sup$ and $\inf$ need not be limit points; they may be isolated.

Comment: @PostNoBills: But, by definition, if x=SupS, every ball B(x,r) intersects $S$; otherwise, x is not the Sup. Similar for the inf. There may be other order relations--not isomorphic to the order of the Reals--where the SupS, InfS are isolated, but not in the Reals, AFAIK. Do you have a (counter) example?

Comment: @user99680 What you said is true. But for $x$ to be a limit point of $x$, every ball $B(x,r)$ must intersect $S\setminus \{x\}$. As for a counterexample: $S=\{1\}$.

Comment: @Post No Bills: Yes; for finite sets this does not apply, but I don't think this is the case in this question (tho I may be wrong). Every finite set is compact. So maybe we can break it into two cases: $K$ finite/discrete, and K infinite/continuous, meaning it has a dense ordering.

Comment: @user99680 The set $S=[1,2]\cup \{3\}$ is infinite, and its supremum is an isolated point.

Comment: @Post No Bills: O.K, there is that third possibility I was not considering. I was referring to infinite with a dense order. But yes, there is that third choice of infinite set with isolated points. Don't mean to nitpick, but maybe I can still keep my point by correcting my condition, arguing component-wise. In a connected component of a compact set, supS and infS are limit points.

Comment: So, my corrected statement is: in any connected compact , infinite set $S$, both $infS$ and $SupS$ are limit points.

Comment: @Post No Bills: Is it O.K if I submit an answer using your comments (I just did, but I will delete if you're not O.K with it.)?

Comment: @user99680 No problem at all.

Comment: Correction: in any connected component  $K$ more than one point, both InfK, SupK are limit points of $K$.

Answer (score 13):

Generally, it's easier to work with open sets than with closed sets. Open sets have less structure: all their points are interior. Closed sets may have two kinds of points: interior  and boundary.

So, I would rather look at $\mathbb R\setminus K$. If $\sup K\in \mathbb R\setminus K$, then by openness, there is an interval $(a,b)$ contained in $\mathbb R\setminus K$ and containing $\sup K$. Show that $a$ is an upper bound for $K$, and you have a contradiction.

> Is closed condition necessary for $\inf$ and $\sup$ [to be contained in the set]?

It's essential for the proof (i.e., we can't just drop it), but it's not necessary in the sense that some sets contain their $\inf$ and $\sup$ without being closed. For example, $[-2,1) \cup (1,2]$.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Answer (score 4):

As $K$ is compact, we have that $K$ is bounded. So $\sup K$ and $\inf K$ exists. By definition $\sup K$, for every $n \in N$ exists $x_n \in K$ such that $\sup K- x_n<1/n$ then $\sup K = \lim x_n$ with $x_n \in K$, as K is closed follows that $\sup K \in K$. To inf is analogous.
Ps: Compact ⇒ closed and bounded.

Comment: How can you make sure that $x_n \neq \sup K$?

Answer (score 0):

A compact set in a metric set is bounded: cover the set by balls of fixed radius $r$, then find a finite subcover by balls of radius $r$. Then consider d: $K \times K \rightarrow \mathbb R$ takes a max $M$ and a min $m$ since $d$ is a continuous function on a compact set . Now consider $d (0,K) : {0} \times K \rightarrow  \mathbb R $ , another continuous, Real-valued function on a compact set, which takes a max M', and a min m'. Then the ball centered at $0^n$ with radius 2(M+M') contains $K$.

Now, for the limit points. For every connected component of $K$ that has more than a singleton, both $SupS, InfS$ are limit points of $S$. If they were not, and there is $r$ with $B(x,r) \cap K =\ $ {} , then $K$ is not connected.  In  $R^n$ , compact implies closed and bounded (tho the argument in the above paragraphfor boundedness of compact in metric space still holds.) Since , in this case SupS, LimS are limit points, and a closed set contains all its limit points, a compact set contains its sup and Inf. In the case $K$ is not connected, this still holds.

Comment: The supremum and infimum need not be limit points.